# Logging keyboard presses in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

Thanks for taking the time to read!

I am trying to assist a student with a study they are doing on Qualtrics. They are presenting a series of faces for 2 seconds each and want the participants to respond with one of two button presses (let's say A and L for example). I need some Javascript that will tell Qualtrics to record which key was pressed for each face.

I've had a look at various pages and tried to fiddle around with some JavaScript (particularly the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852723/how-can-i-add-a-keydown-function-to-qualtrics)), but I am a complete scripting noob and keep getting either error messages or script that just doesn't record any key presses.

Any and all help much appreciated :)

Comment: Why not just build a form with 2 radio buttons? The functionality to accomplish this is built into Qualtrics, really no reason for custom JS.

Comment: I've done the whole 'why are you doing this, this would be better off in [insert other programme here]' spiel to no avail. You can lead a horse to water...

I imagine the issue is that the radio buttons are too small and would require more complex movement than simply having your fingers ready on the buttons